# Magento mail sending error

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

When i have sending magento order mail, following exception generated at every time. how to fix it ?

> 2016-06-23T03:58:08+00:00 ERR (3): exception 'Zend_Mail_Transport_Exception' with message 'Unable to send mail. ' in /home/embiconi/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport /Sendmail.php:137 Stack trace:
>
> 0 /home/embiconi/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail/Transport/Abstract.php(348):
> Zend_Mail_Transport_Sendmail->_sendMail()
> 1 /home/embiconi/public_html/lib/Zend/Mail.php(1194):
> Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
> 2 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email
> /Queue.php(241): Zend_Mail->send()
> 3 [internal function]:
> Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue->send(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule))
> 4 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model
> /Observer.php(326): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
> 5 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Cron/Model
> /Observer.php(72): Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->_processJob(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Schedule), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
> 6 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1357):
> Mage_Cron_Model_Observer->dispatch(Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
> 7 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1336):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->_callObserverMethod(Object(Mage_Cron_Model_Observer), 'dispatch', Object(Varien_Event_Observer))
> 8 /home/embiconi/public_html/app/Mage.php(448):
> Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('default', Array)
> 9 /home/embiconi/public_html/cron.php(76): Mage::dispatchEvent('default')
> {main}

Comment: it shows that sendmail function is not working on server.  
initially to check, try to send a mail from standalone php file from the server.

Comment: Please check that on your server, the email server is configured to send emails.

Comment: Please send mail with mail command, you need to first install the mail command and run the command as -

mail -s "subject" mailld@gmail.com 

and it will give you prompt to write something and to close that press Ctrl+d to send email.

Comment: simple php mail function is working. but in magento error occured

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this one?
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Hope it can solve your problem.